Protected routes in nextjs
I couldn't make protected route in nextjs, with configuration of next-intl, who can help?
I made any configuration but not working
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import createIntlMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { locales, localePrefix } from "./config/i18n";

// Create the i18n middleware
const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
  defaultLocale: "en",
  locales,
  localePrefix,
});

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  // Handle locale redirection first using next-intl middleware
  const localeRedirect = intlMiddleware(req);
  if (localeRedirect) {
    // Ensure locale is applied before checking authentication
    return localeRedirect;
  }

  // Retrieve cookies using Next.js 13+ API
  const token = req.cookies.get("access-token")?.value  "";
  const role = req.cookies.get("user-roles")?.value  "";

  // DEBUG: Log to server-side terminal to check if cookies are correctly retrieved
  console.log("Token from cookies:", token);
  console.log("Role from cookies:", role);

  // Allow access to public pages without requiring a login
  if (
    pathname === "/login" 
    pathname === "/register" 
    pathname.startsWith("/public")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.next(); // Allow access to login, register, and public pages
  }

  // Redirect to login if the user is not logged in (no token)
  if (!token) {
    console.log("No token found, redirecting to /login");
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
  }

  // Role-based access control for protected routes
  if (pathname.startsWith("/admin") && role !== "admin") {
    console.log("Non-admin user tried to access /admin");
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/not-authorized", req.url));
  }

  if (pathname.startsWith("/teacher") && role !== "teacher") {
    console.log("Non-teacher user tried to access /teacher");
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/not-authorized", req.url));
  }

  if (pathname.startsWith("/student") && role !== "student") {
    console.log("Non-student user tried to access /student");
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/not-authorized", req.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next(); // Allow access if authenticated and authorized
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/dashboard",
    "/courses/:path*",
    "/admin/:path*",
    "/teacher/:path*",
    "/student/:path*",
    "/(ru|en|uz)/:path*", // Locale handling
    "/((?!_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)", // Locale handling + ignoring internal Next.js routes
  ],
};

